# Issue with cross compilation of boost 1.65.0 library on windows for raspberry pi 3b+ 64-bit Linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile boost 1.65.0 libraries on windows 11 for raspberry pi 3b+.
I am using the VS2019 developer command prompt to build the libraries.
I have configured the user-config.jam file in the home directory with the following line:

```
using gcc : arm : C:/SysGCC/raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe ;
```

and have run the .\bootstrap command on the prompt window.

Further, I have run the following command specifying the following details:

```
.\b2 -j8 toolset=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared stage --stagedir=stage/aarch64
```

Unfortunately, I am getting error as follows:

```
arm.jam: No such file or directory
```

Error details:

```
D:\Dev\boost_1_65_0>.\b2 -j8 toolset=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ target-os=linux link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared stage --stagedir=stage/aarch64 

warning: Did not find command for MSVC toolset. If you have Visual Studio 2017 installed you will need to TOOLS for your installation, or build from the 'Visual Studio Command Prompt for VS 2017'. 

"'D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx86/vcvarsall. command,
operable program or batch file.
"'D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx86/vcvarsall.bat'"
command,
coperable program or batch file.
D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx86/vcvarsall.bat'"
command,
operable program or batch file.
"'D:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx86/vcvarsall.bat'"
command,
operable program or batch file. arm.jam: No such file or directory
D:/Dev/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using
ERROR: rule "arm.init" unknown in module "toolset".
D:/Dev/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:461: in process-explicit-toolset-requests
D:/Dev/boost_1_65_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:527: in load
D:\Dev\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
D:\Dev\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build D:\Dev\boost_1_65_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

How to resolve this issue to build the libraries successfully?

Please note: I am relatively new to using Linux and cross-compilation from windows and looking forward to understand the concepts better.

Comment: I am a bit confused, you are using a compiler targeting Aarch32 and your stage directory is named stage/aarch64: Could you please augment your original question with the exact architecture you want to build boost++ for, i.e. is your target raspberry pi 3b+ running a 32 bit or a 64 bit version of Linux ?

Comment: I have currently installed a 64-bit Linux on my 3b+ and wish to build boost libraries for it on the windows machine

Comment: Please don't post images of errors. Post errors as text (formatted as code).

Comment: @sre In this case, you should use [aarch64-none-linux-g++](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.3-2021.07/binrel/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-mingw-w64-i686-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz)  instead of arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++. And you should specify `arm64` instead of `arm`in the .jam file.  Please note that this will not solve your problem, but this will  help generating the libraries for the right target.

Comment: VS2019 developer command prompt is for running MSVC. If you want to use gcc, try a regular plain command prompt.